# when iam paasing arugment to helper from controller iam getting error magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, controllers, helper, object-manager

**Iam Getting the below error**

> Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
>   could not be converted to string in
>   /var/www/html/development/amt/app/code/vendor/RequestForQuote/Controller/Index/Index.php
>   on line 153 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Recoverable
>   Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager could
>   not be converted to string in
>   /var/www/html/development/amt/app/code/vendor/RequestForQuote/Controller/Index/Index.php
>   on line 153 at
>   /var/www/html/development/amt/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
>   []

**My Controller :**

```
<?php

namespace Sm\RequestForQuote\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */

    protected $resultPageFactory;
     /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var MailInterface
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;
    /*** @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context*/

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $emailHelper;

     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Sm\RequestForQuote\Helper\Email $emailHelper,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LoggerInterface $logger = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('/customer/account/');
        }
        try {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
            $this->sendEmail($cart);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $cartObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->truncate(); 
            $cartObject->saveQuote();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
        }
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
    public function sendEmail($cart)
    {
        $country = $street = $post = $city = " ";
        $ad = [];   
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerSession->getCustomer();
            $name =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();  // get  Full Name
            $email = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
            $number = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($number);
            $customerNumber = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_number')->getValue();
            foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address) {
                $country = $address->getCountryId();
                $ad = $address->getStreet();
                $street = $ad[0];
                $post = $address->getPostcode();
                $city = $address->getCity();
            }
        }

         $sender_name = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('requestforquote/sender/sender_name', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
         $sender_mail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('requestforquote/sender/sender_mail', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
         $receiver_name = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('requestforquote/receiver/receiver_name', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
         $receiver_mail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('requestforquote/receiver/receiver_mail', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


        /* Here we prepare data for our email  */
        /* Receiver Detail  */
        $receiverInfo = [
            'name' => $receiver_name,
            'email' => "vins@arizon.digital"
        ];


        /* Sender Detail  */
        $senderInfo = [
            'name' => $sender_name,
            'email' => "support@arizon.digital"
        ];

        /* Assign values for your template variables  */
        $emailTemplateVariables = array();
        $emailTempVariables['name'] = $name;
        $emailTempVariables['email'] = $email;
        $emailTempVariables['customerNumber'] = $customerNumber;
        $emailTempVariables['country'] = $country;
        $emailTempVariables['street'] = $street;
        $emailTempVariables['post'] = $post;
        $emailTempVariables['city'] = $city;
        $emailTempVariables['items'] = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();


        /* We write send mail function in helper because if we want to 
           use same in other action then we can call it directly from helper */  

        /* call send mail method from helper or where you define it*/  
    $this->emailHelper->yourCustomMailSendMethod($emailTempVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);
    }
```

}

**My Helper :**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\RequestForQuote\Helper;

/**
 * Custom Module Email helper
 */
class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD  = 'vendoe/RequestForQuote/quote_email_template';
    /* Here section and group refer to name of section and group where you create this field in configuration*/

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
    */
    protected $temp_id;

    /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    * @param Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \vendor\RequestForQuote\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder; 
    }

    /**
     * Return store configuration value of your template field that which id you set for template
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getConfigValue($path, $storeId)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return store 
     *
     * @return Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

    /**
     * Return template id according to store
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTemplateId($xmlPath)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue($xmlPath, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());
    }

    /**
     * [generateTemplate description]  with template file and tempaltes variables values                
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables 
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo             
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo           
     * @return void
     */
    public function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {
        $name = str_replace(' ', '_',$emailTemplateVariables['name']);
        $fileName = "quote_".strtolower($name)."_".time(). '.csv';

        $content = "S.no,Sku,Name,Qty,Price\n";
        $items = $emailTemplateVariables['items'];
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($items as $item){
            $sku = $item->getSku();
            $name = $item->getName();
            $Qty = $item->getQty();
            $Price = $item->getPrice();
            $content.= ++$counter.','.$sku.','.$name.','.$Qty.','.$Price."\n";
        }
        $template =  $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('vendor_RequestForQuote_quote_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, /* here you can defile area and
                                                                                 store of template for which you prepare it */
                        'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name'])
                ->addAttachment($content, $fileName, 'application/csv');
        return $this;        
    }
    /**
     * [sendInvoicedOrderEmail description]                  
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables 
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo             
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo           
     * @return void
     */
    /* your send mail method*/
    public function yourCustomMailSendMethod($emailTemplateVariables, $senderInfo, $receiverInfo)
    {
        $this->temp_id = $this->getTemplateId('vendor_RequestForQuote_quote_email_template');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();    
        $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);    
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();        
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }

}
```

When I used helper function it's give me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**please avoid obectManager**

> Add this into your **My Controller**

```
 protected $emamilHelper;

 public function __construct(
    ..........................................
    \vendor\RequestForQuote\Helper\Email  $emamilHelper,
    ..........................................
) {
    ..........................................
    $this->emamilHelper = $emamilHelper;
    ..........................................
}
```

Now you can call Your Helper function like this

```
 $this->emamilHelper->HelperFunctionName(); //  call your helper function
```

Comment: Iam getting blank page when doing this type

Comment: @Sabareesh above is not full code only that part how to call helper function.

Comment: $this->emailHelper->yourCustomMailSendMethod($emailTempVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo); i used in that same way

Comment: yes this is right way to call helper function

Comment: But iam getting blank page if take this line iam getting the page

Comment: In your code has something wrong please check your code.

Comment: Is there any mistake in passing parameter or in helper

Comment: Update your Question please

Comment: We can pass the array as parameter ? @msqare

Comment: yes we can pass array as parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106002/discussion-between-sabareesh-and-msquare).